# Worklight push - iOS Notification center delete

Tags: ios, push, ibm-mobilefirst

Our worklight hybrid application works fine, and send push messages. The messages are good, and they appear in iOS notfication center. We tested in 6.1 and 6.2 with the same result.

The problem:
When server send more than one message they are appear in notification center, but selecting one of them delete all messages that came from same source.

Comment: Open settings->Notification center->scroll down to your application -> in alert section -> include see how many recent items are selected. probabily this could be the problem

Answer (score 1):

Open settings->Notification center->scroll down to your application -> in alert section -> include see how many recent items are selected. probabily this could be the problem

Comment: The default is 5 recent item. I tried to change it to 1, but its not help. In this case the second message overwrite the first one without doing anything.